# Vertical Scrollbar becomes sticky with mouse after clicked in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

I am facing problem with Vertical scrollbar in IE, when I click the scrollbar, it becomes stick with mouse and unable to release after mouse click released and where ever I move mouse, it is continuously follow.

Kindly advice workaround on this.

```css
.scrollbar {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: auto;
    color: black;
    
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    scrollbar-face-color: #E21F25;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #E21F25;
    scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    scrollbar-highlight-color: aqua;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #808080;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-Color: #E21F25;
}
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" style="width: 500px;" class="tab-pane fade" id="layerOverlay">
    <div class="mapContentHeaderHolder">
        <h4 class="mapContentHeader">Layer Overlay</h4>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img class="minPanel" src="Images/w_down.png" title="Minimise" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closePanel">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="mapContentInfoHolder" onmouseover="commonFunctions.closeToolTipDialog();">
            <div class="formElementsRow">
                <div id="jstree">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution as below :-

$('#layerOverlay').draggable({
            cancel: '.scrollbar'
        }); // cancel: .scrollbar => to disable sticky //draggable when focus on scrollbar css selector